# the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly

Tags: dart

I was debugging my project. After some execution, it started showing an error saying that the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly (see screenshot below). I also updated my dart SDK, but nothing happened. I did search on Google, but found nothing that helped.

[image: Error which shown in console]

Comment: Try running your build in the terminal using `flutter run -v <deviceName>`.

Comment: In the future, it's much easier for the community to review and answer these types of questions if you include the code—or, in this case, the error message—inside your question, instead of as a screenshot. This allows them to be copied, searched for, and easily read. None of those are easy with a screenshot.

Answer (score 9):

try this may help

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: It might be useful to offer an explanation of what the `clean` command does, and why it's useful in these types of situations.

Comment: it clears the flutter build cache, Not sure but i had the same issue and its helped me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case `flutter clean` cant help. My flutter/bin/cache folder was corrupted. Deleting flutter/bin/cache folder and then running command `flutter`, downloads dart SDK and then setting up the flutter sdk path by giving your flutter folder path in Android Studio -> Preferences -> Languages and Frameworks -> Flutter , solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue could also happen when you have migrated to Null-Safety. The reason is that when migrating to Null-Safety, all packages need to also be migrated to Null-Safety, thus it will return an error saying:

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:
```

Also, it will give you a [link](https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety) for you to reference:

```
For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Unsupported Null Safety mode NonNullableByDefaultCompiledMode.Invalid, in null.
```

Since this issue results in an error, you won't be able to run your project or package unless all packages in your dependencies are null-safety migrated. The dart compiler will end after this.

```
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)
```

If you get the issue and you are sure that all packages are up-to-date and that all support Null-Safety, try running `flutter clean`. This will clear or packages in your project and reinstall them, cache files will also be removed.

Please leave down a comment if you may have any suggestions, or edit this answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after adding package `golden_toolkit` and one golden test I wrote for it.  Removing the test file and the dependency from pubspec.yaml and then running `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

delete flutter/bin/cache then type in terminal flutter clean then flutter run
that's work for me

Answer (score 0):

My case was really strange and I don't know were it comes from, is it VS or Dart
The point is somewhere here where I set my class as the generic of the base class: `class MyClass extends MyBaseClass<MyClass>` and add an instance to the VS WATCH and set a beark point after the instance creation.

```
class MyBaseClass<T> {}

class MyClass extends MyBaseClass<MyClass> {
  @override
  String toString() => "MyClassObject";
}

main() {
  MyClass o = MyClass();
  print(o); // If you add 'o' to your WATCH items and add a breakpoint here it will crash
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add any packages it can be the problem.
just use
`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`
`flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

By adding this flutter pub add --dev flutter_lints to terminal resolved my problem